# How to make Constructor for entityclass in springboot that extends mappedsuperclass

Tags: java, spring-boot, constructor, superclass, spring-mvc-test

step1: I have mappedsuperclass that has constructor.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class CommonConfig{
    
    @JsonFormat
    @Column(name ="LastModifiedTime")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    protected  Date lastModifiedTime;
    
    @JsonProperty
    @NonNull
    @Column(name = "IsActive")
    protected boolean isActive;
     
    @NonNull
    @Column(name = "ModifiedUserID")
    private int modifiedUserID; 
    public CommonConfig(Date lastModifiedTime, boolean isActive, int modifiedUserID) {
        this.lastModifiedTime = lastModifiedTime;
        this.isActive = isActive;
        this.modifiedUserID = modifiedUserID;
    }
```

step 2: My base class goes here, tell how to construct a constructor for my bases.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "config_impact")
public class ConfigImpact extends CommonConfig {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ImpactID")
    private Integer id;
    
    @NonNull
    @Column(name = "ImpactName")
    private String impactName;
    @NonNull
    @Column(name = "Description")
    private String description;
    
      
    
    public ConfigImpact(Integer id, String impactName, String description) {
        super(lastModifiedTime, isActive, modifiedUserID);        
        this.id = id;
        this.impactName = impactName;
     
this.description = description;
    }
```

how to create constructor for base class it gives me a error. Tell me a way i am stuck at here.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ConfigImpact` constructor should be like this:

```
public ConfigImpact(Date lastModifiedTime, boolean isActive, int modifiedUserID, Integer id, String impactName, String description) {
        super(lastModifiedTime, isActive, modifiedUserID);        
        this.id = id;
        this.impactName = impactName;
        this.description = description;
    }
```